# gdb - how to make it call a program with a relative name

Tags: gdb

`gdb` seems to be calling a debugged program with an absolute name `/home/somebody/dir/progname`. How do I make it call a program with a relative name? Like `./progname`?

It seems like I cannot do it with `set args`.

I also tried to alter stack contents to replace the absolute name of a program with a relative one, but `gdb` was stubborn still. I changed a program's name that was almost at the beginning of stack, but what I received in my strout was still an absolute name (even though `x /s` on this address gave me a relative path).

Thanks!

*PS. A quick explanation - I was messing with an assembly and had bad time writing a program`s name into strout - it was writing out a full name normally and a relative name cut off. The error was fixed (stupid as usual), but the question persisted. I tired to reproduce what was going on in debugger with no luck.*